# Как вычесть из даты число, если дата возвращается в результате выполнения вложенного запроса?

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, дата

Есть дата, которая хранится в таблице с глобальными переменными, т.е. строка в таблице, в которой один из интересующих меня параметров хранит дату в столбце `value`. Следующим запросом я получаю эту дату:

```
SELECT value FROM TableGlobalParams tbl
WHERE tbl.parameter='DMDPOSTDATE'
```

Запрос возвращает `12/1/2019`. Из этой даты мне необходимо вычесть значение значение 1 и значение другого глобального параметра, который равен 14.

```
SELECT value FROM TableGlobalParams tbl
WHERE tbl.parameter='INT_HOR_DMD'
```

Получил 14 в результате выполнения последнего запроса.

Как мне построить формулу, чтобы я получал сначала `DMDPOSTDATE`, а потом в том же запросе вычитал из неё 1 и значение `INT_HOR_DMD`?

Пробовал привести значение через `TO_DATE` во вложенном запросе, не понимает:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SELECT value FROM TableGlobalParams tbl
WHERE tbl.parameter='DMDPOSTDATE','mm:dd:yyyy')-1
FROM Dual
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  TO_DATE(post.value) - delta.value
FROM
  TableGlobalParams post
  JOIN TableGlobalParams delta ON (
    delta.parameter='INT_HOR_DMD'
  )
WHERE
  post.parameter='DMDPOSTDATE'
```

Или так

```
SELECT 
  TO_DATE(post.value) - delta.value
FROM
  TableGlobalParams post,
  TableGlobalParams delta
WHERE
  post.parameter='DMDPOSTDATE' AND
  delta.parameter='INT_HOR_DMD'
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно с помощью скалярного подзапроса:

```sql
with TableGlobalParams (parameter, value) as (
    select 'DMDPOSTDATE', '12/1/2019' from dual union all
    select 'INT_HOR_DMD', '14'        from dual union all
    select 'SOME_PARAM',  'unused'    from dual 
)
select to_date (value, 'mm/dd/yyyy') - (
    select to_number (value, '9999')  
    from TableGlobalParams 
    where parameter = 'INT_HOR_DMD'
    ) - 1 res
from TableGlobalParams  
where parameter = 'DMDPOSTDATE';
```

или c перекрестным соединением таблиц:

```sql
select to_date (p1.value, 'mm/dd/yyyy') - to_number (p2.value, '9999') - 1 res  
from TableGlobalParams p1 cross join TableGlobalParams p2
where p1.parameter = 'DMDPOSTDATE'
and   p2.parameter = 'INT_HOR_DMD';
```

Оба запроса выведут:

```
RES                
-------------------
2019-11-16 00:00:00
```

Kaкой запрос лучше по производительности, нужно смотреть планы выполнения на реальных данных. Если данных заведомо немного, выберите тот, который лучше читается.